# Filter a Dataframe by months and year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from which I am getting month and year values in a column like the following:

```
temp dd   delivery_month       
0        02-2021      #mm-yyyy
1        01-2021      
2        02-2021  
3        02-2021
```

I want to use the month and year from all of the rows in that column to filter another dataframe
but I got the following error:

> Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

The date in the second dataframe is like the following:

```
 allot_df['dispatch_date'][0]   06-01-2020
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
    for row in temp_dd.itertuples():

        allot_df = allot_df[allot_df['dispatch_date'].dt.month == row.delivery_month[:2]]
```

where `temp_dd` is the first dataframe

How can I filter the `allot_df` dataframe by both month and year from `temp_dd`?

Comment: I guess "dispatch_date" dtype is not datetime. Could you run print(allot_df.dtypes) ?
If it is not datetime, you may want to convert it first : allot_df['dispatch_date'] = pd.to_datetime(allot_df['dispatch_date'])

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is values not datetimes, if format `mm-YYYY` use:

```
allot_df['dispatch_date'] = pd.to_datetime(allot_df['dispatch_date'], format='%m-%Y')
```

Comment: I am getting ValueError: time data '06-01-2020' does not match format '%m-%Y' (match)

Comment: @RahulSharma - So need `allot_df['dispatch_date'] = pd.to_datetime(allot_df['dispatch_date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')` if datetimes format is `DD-MM-YYYY` ?

Comment: Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66115994/multiple-filters-in-a-dataframe

Comment: I am trying to figure out why the filter is not working with dates

Comment: @RahulSharma - I see, without real data hard to test.