# Multiple filters in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a Dataframe but it returns empty dataframe when I run the following code:

```
allot_df = allot_df[(allot_df['dispatch_date'].dt.month == 1) &
                                (allot_df['dispatch_date'].dt.year == 2021 ) &
                                (allot_df['Increased Cycle Time'] > 0) &
                                (allot_df['kit']==row.kit)]
```

But when I apply the same filters via excel it works fine
I am not able to identify the problem in the code

Thus I ran it with fix values but still the same error

The original code should be:

```
allot_df = allot_df[(allot_df['dispatch_date'].dt.month == int(row.delivery_month[:2])) &
                                (allot_df['dispatch_date'].dt.year == int(row.delivery_month[-4:])) &
                                (allot_df['Increased Cycle Time'] > 0)&
                                (allot_df['kit']==row.kit)]
```

I tried printing the values of the variable to se the mismatch but they are same

```
print("month df", row.delivery_month[:2])
print("month df", row.kit)
print("month df", type(row.delivery_month[:2]))

month df 02
month df KIT1216A
month df <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to but `.iloc` in the query. See below:

```py
allot_df = allot_df.iloc[(allot_df['dispatch_date'].dt.month == 1) &
                                (allot_df['dispatch_date'].dt.year == 2021 ) &
                                (allot_df['Increased Cycle Time'] > 0) &
                                (allot_df['kit']==row.kit)]
```